# How to play M3U8 audio from video in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a URL. Which contains number of URLs with .ts extension. When i select one .ts URL , it contains number of Video files URL. Now I have to play that Video only AUDIO PART not VIDEO.. How can i do this?

URL is [CLICK HERE](http://link.theplatform.com/s/flac/61TtrN_uN37k?mbr=true&feed=FoxPlay%20Live%20Events&manifest=m3u&auth=ow_NDz5-lv1GX63uSIn4EfBk4GBAkGCA)

```
private void playSong() {
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(url));
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        mp.prepareAsync();
    //  Log.d("*** AUDIO DURATION ***", mp.getDuration() + "  " + "  ");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly keeps you from playing just audio? Because your code looks ok to me...

Comment: I am new to How to play with M3U8 so i dont know what to do .. please ;et me know if u have any idea to use it

Comment: The code you've posted is enough to play audio from url. Just start it witth mp.start().

Comment: yes its playing mp3 but my need is to Listen a audio from VIdeo without Seeing video.. and that sound should be play in background using service

Comment: Doesn't matter. MediaPlayer will play happily mp3, ogg, flac, avi and others without any changes to above code. And it will play it asynchronically.

Comment: No sir... I am getting trouble to play M3U8 which contains number of urls...

Comment: Thnxx a lot @ssuukk..... finally i got it..... Thnx for being with me...:-)